# Python: dispatched on-line processing of high volume real-time datastreams

Tags: python, bigdata, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, data-stream

I have some **high volume datastreams coming in on different websockets** (sensor data - several TBs per month), for which

I want to **guarantee that all data is stored**, even during high load.

So I want to **dispatch the data to my database and real-time processing module** (e.g. GUI, ML predictions etc), in a way that

it **buffers the datastreams**, in case the processing of said modules is too slow, and so that these can **'catch-up' when the load decreases**.

**What I tried:**
python threads with queues (from Queue module or threading module) but if it's blocking, I can't ensure the  data is not congested and if its non blocking (e.g. asyncio.Queue) I get race conditions and things blow up.

So maybe I should use some kind of callback methods but I don't know what to look for. I hope the question is not too vague. **If anybody had a pointer to what I could try**, optimally using python only, that would really help me a lot, even if its just an idea.

Comment: [Apache kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) is a good streaming tool and you can use it in python by [faust](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

Answer (score 0):

> So maybe I should use some kind of callback methods but I don't know what to look for.

Looks like you need a `Future`.

- [`concurrent.futures.Future()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)
- [`asyncio.Future()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future)

> What I tried: python threads with queues (from Queue module or threading module) but if it's blocking, I can't ensure the data is not congested and if its non blocking (e.g. asyncio.Queue) I get race conditions and things blow up.

You can try to use non-blocking methods of `Queue`:

- [`Queue.put_nowait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put_nowait)
- [`Queue.get_nowait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get_nowait)

and query database when `queue.Empty` or `queue.Full` exception caught.

Comment: That looks very promising, thanks a lot! I will give it a try and report back here.